# message.body.decoded email display is a mess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, html-email, mail-gem

I'm receiving email into my rails app but setting the email body to `message.body.decoded` displays the email as a mess. An example is below. Is there a better way to display the email body? Or alternatively is there a way to forward the email to another email address without decoding and re-encoding it?

message.body.decoded example:

```
--Apple-Mail=_C8C99366-9FF9-4DD0-AA35-6469D60C3701 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252 Begin forwarded message: > From: "Herringbone" <style@herringbone.com>=20 > Subject: Don't miss out on our Multi Buy Shirt Offer - ends Sunday! > Date: 6 September, 2012 7:08:15 PM PDT > To: "Nick" <nickkarrasch@gmail.com> > Reply-To: style@herringbone.com >=20 > =09 >=20 > Having trouble viewing this email? Click here to see the web version. >=20 >=20 > =09 >=20 >=20 >=20 > =09 > Dear Nick >=20 > Don't miss out on our famous Multi Buy Shirt Offer - ends this Sunday. >=20 > Shop now for new styles available instore and online! > =20 >=20 >=20 >=20 >=20 >=20 >=20 > Facebook=20 > www.facebook.com/HerringboneSydney    = Herringbone=92s official blog=20 > http://herringbonetheweave.tumblr.com/=09 >=20 >=20 >=20 > This email was sent to Nick > To ensure that our messages get to you (and don't go to your junk or = bulk email folders), > please add style@herringbone.com to your address book. >=20 > Enquiries? Contact us directly! +61 2 9362 9901 > Visit us instore! Click here for Herringbone locations > Don't want to hear from us anymore? Click here to Unsubscribe >=20 >=20 >=20 >=20 >=20 > =20 >=20 --Apple-Mail=_C8C99366-9FF9-4DD0-AA35-6469D60C3701 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252 <html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html = charset=3Dwindows-1252"><base href=3D"x-msg://890/"></head><body = style=3D"word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; = -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; "><br><div><br><div>Begin = forwarded message:</div><br = class=3D"Apple-interchange-newline"><blockquote type=3D"cite"><div = style=3D"margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; = margin-left: 0px;"><span style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; = font-size:medium; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);"><b>From: </b></span><span = style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size:medium;">"Herringbone" = &lt;<a href=3D"mailto:style@herringbone.com">style@herringbone.com</a>&gt;= <br></span></div><div style=3D"margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; = margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"><span = style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size:medium; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, = 1.0);"><b>Subject: </b></span><span style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; = font-size:medium;"><b>Don't miss out on our Multi Buy Shirt Offer - ends = Sunday!</b><br></span></div><div style=3D"margin-top: 0px; margin-right: = 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"><span = style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size:medium; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, = 1.0);"><b>Date: </b></span><span style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; = font-size:medium;">6 September, 2012 7:08:15 PM PDT<br></span></div><div = style=3D"margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; = margin-left: 0px;"><span style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; = font-size:medium; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);"><b>To: </b></span><span = style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size:medium;">"Nick" &lt;<a = href=3D"mailto:nickkarrasch@gmail.com">nickkarrasch@gmail.com</a>&gt;<br><= /span></div><div style=3D"margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; = margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"><span = style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size:medium; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, = 1.0);"><b>Reply-To: </b></span><span style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica'; = font-size:medium;"><a = href=3D"mailto:style@herringbone.com">style@herringbone.com</a><br></span>= </div><br><div leftmargin=3D"0" marginwidth=3D"0" topmargin=3D"0" = marginheight=3D"0" bgcolor=3D"#f7f7f7" style=3D"font-family: Helvetica; = font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; = font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; = orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: = none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; = -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; "><table = width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" = bgcolor=3D"#f7f7f7"><tbody><tr><td width=3D"50%">&nbsp;</td><td><table = cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"600"><tbody><tr><td = colspan=3D"3" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"20" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" align=3D"center" = style=3D"text-align: center; "><font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, = sans-serif" size=3D"1" color=3D"#666666" style=3D"font-size: 10px; = line-height: 12px; ">Having trouble viewing this email?<span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-e-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-r/">Click = here to see the web version.</a></font></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"16" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" = bgcolor=3D"#e7e7e7" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td width=3D"1" bgcolor=3D"#e7e7e7" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td><table cellpadding=3D"0" = cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"598" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><tbody><tr><td = colspan=3D"3" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"53" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" valign=3D"top" = align=3D"center" style=3D"text-align: center; font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><a href=3D"#" style=3D"text-decoration: none; "><img = src=3D"http://i3.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/logo.gif" width=3D"242"= height=3D"47" border=3D"0" alt=3D"Herringbone = Sidney"></a></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"47" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td width=3D"9" style=3D"font-size: = 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td><table width=3D"580" cellpadding=3D"0" = cellspacing=3D"0"><tbody><tr><td><table cellpadding=3D"0" = cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"422" align=3D"center"><tbody><tr><td = style=3D"text-align: center; "><font face=3D"'Times New Roman', Times, = serif" size=3D"1" color=3D"#00274c" style=3D"font-size: 13px; = line-height: 15px; ">Dear Nick</font></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"font-size:= 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"19" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td><font face=3D"Times New Roman, = Times New Roman, Times, seriff" size=3D"1" color=3D"#00274c" = style=3D"font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; ">Don't miss out on our = famous<span class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-j/">Multi = Buy Shirt Offer</a><span class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>- = ends this Sunday.<br><br><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-t/">Shop = now</a><span class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>for new styles = available&nbsp;<a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-h/">instore</a= ><span class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>and<span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-k/">online</a>= !<br>&nbsp;</font><img = src=3D"http://i10.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/text-herringbone.gif" = width=3D"186" vspace=3D"0" hspace=3D"0" align=3D"right" border=3D"0" = alt=3D"image description" label=3D"Herringbone"></td></tr><tr><td = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"23" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding=3D"0"= cellspacing=3D"0" bgcolor=3D"#002a4d" width=3D"580" = align=3D"center"><tbody><tr><td style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; = "><img src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" = width=3D"1" height=3D"10" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" = align=3D"left" alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-u/" = style=3D"text-decoration: none; "><img = src=3D"http://i1.cmail1.com/ei/j/FA/9FD/E2A/csimport/MainImage.120359.jpg"= width=3D"580" vspace=3D"0" hspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"Multi-Buy Shirt Offer" label=3D"Call to Action" = height=3D"724"></a></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"10" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding=3D"0"= cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"580"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor=3D"#00273e" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"19" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td><table cellpadding=3D"0" = cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"580"><tbody><tr><td width=3D"24" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"35" valign=3D"middle" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i7.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/img-fb.gif" = width=3D"26" height=3D"26" vspace=3D"0" hspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" = align=3D"left" alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"1" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i8.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/sep-1.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"39" vspace=3D"0" hspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"10" style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"220" valign=3D"middle" = style=3D"line-height: 14px; "><font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, = sans-serif" size=3D"1" color=3D"#00273e" style=3D"line-height: 14px; = ">Facebook<span class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-o/" = style=3D"text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 39, 62); "><font = color=3D"#00273e">www.facebook.com/HerringboneSydney</font></a></font></td= ><td width=3D"10" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"71 valign=3D" middle""=3D"" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><a href=3D"#" = style=3D"text-decoration: none; "><img = src=3D"http://i9.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/partner-logo-1.gif" = width=3D"61" height=3D"39" vspace=3D"0" hspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" = align=3D"left" alt=3D"The weave"></a></td><td width=3D"1" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i8.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/sep-1.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"39" vspace=3D"0" hspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"9" style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td><td width=3D"189" valign=3D"middle" = style=3D"line-height: 14px; "><font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, = sans-serif" size=3D"1" color=3D"#00273e" style=3D"line-height: 14px; = ">Herringbone=92s official blog<span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-l-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-b/" = style=3D"text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 39, 62); "><font = color=3D"#00273e">http://herringbonetheweave.tumblr.com/</font></a></font>= </td><td width=3D"10" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"18" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor=3D"#00273e" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding=3D"0"= cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"580"><tbody><tr><td style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"19" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td align=3D"center"><font = face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size=3D"1" color=3D"#00274c" = style=3D"font-size: 10px; line-height: 14px; ">This email was sent to = Nick<br>To ensure that our messages get to you (and don't go to your = junk or bulk email folders),<br>please add<span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a = href=3D"mailto:style@herringbone.com">style@herringbone.com</a><span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>to your address = book.<br><br>Enquiries? Contact us directly! +61 2 9362 9901<br>Visit us = instore!<span class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a href=3D"#" = style=3D"text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 39, 76); "><font = color=3D"#00274c">Click here</font></a><span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>for Herringbone = locations<br>Don't want to hear from us anymore?<span = class=3D"Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a = href=3D"http://herringbone.cmail1.com/t/j-u-ghuidl-vudjkiuk-y/">Click = here to Unsubscribe</a></font></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"font-size: 0px; = line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"24" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img = description"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td = width=3D"9" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td width=3D"1" = bgcolor=3D"#e7e7e7" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" = bgcolor=3D"#e7e7e7" style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3D"3" = style=3D"font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; "><img = src=3D"http://i2.cmail1.com/ti/j/1B/C6A/366/132258/none.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"40" hspace=3D"0" vspace=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"left" = alt=3D"img description"></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td = width=3D"50%">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table><img = src=3D"https://cmail1.com/t/j-o-ghuidl-vudjkiuk/o.gif" width=3D"1" = height=3D"1" border=3D"0" style=3D"height: 1px !important; width: 1px = !important; border-width: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; = padding: 0px !important; "></div></blockquote></div><br></body></html>= --Apple-Mail=_C8C99366-9FF9-4DD0-AA35-6469D60C3701--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section [Reading a Multipart Email](https://github.com/mikel/mail#reading-a-multipart-email) in the mail gem docs.

For example, if you want to do something with the HTML part of an email, you would have to find the part with content type 'text/html', and call **decode_body** on that.

```
mail = Mail.read('example_multipart_mail.eml')
mail.parts.each do |part|
  next unless part.content_type =~ /^text\/html/
  puts part.decode_body
end
```